# Python script to parse first image of search engine from list of keywords in CSV

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mysql-workbench

I have this code below that is supposed to save an image in my local directory from a search engine. It does, however it saves it as a hex file. I can mess with the code and get lucky, but I hope someone here can give me the best solution.

If I open the hex file in notepad++ I notice the first row of the hex file says "‰PNG". I manually changed the file extension and the correct image shows up.

That is my first issue with this code. I'm just trying to get a better understanding of it.

I also wanted to throw in a list of key words to parse and return whatever number of images, default is 1 according to the script. Is it possible to tell python to read through a column of search Queries and save the image files as the search query? If it's easier, I use mysql workbench to work on my database. I have a column that I want to execute this script on but maybe instead return the filename whilst saving it into a local directory.

For example, my first search was for "HP C9730A" which is a printer toner product. How can I send a list of part numbers may it be a csv or json array and return the parsed images saved exactly like the keywords used? So filename would be "HP C9730A.jpg"

I noticed the clause in the script states:

```
<b>else</b> 'jpg'
```

The first image on google using my example as mentioned before is a PNG file. Is this why my file isn't saving?

Either way, can you help? me not only to save jpg or png images, but also save them as the search keywords with possible batch processing using csv or json array with many different keywords.

```
import argparse
import json
import itertools
import logging
import re
import os
import uuid
import sys
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def configure_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s]: %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

logger = configure_logging()

REQUEST_HEADER = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}


def get_soup(url, header):
    response = urlopen(Request(url, headers=header))
    return BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

def get_query_url(query):
    return "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%s&source=lnms&tbm=isch" % query

def extract_images_from_soup(soup):
    image_elements = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rg_meta"})
    metadata_dicts = (json.loads(e.text) for e in image_elements)
    link_type_records = ((d["ou"], d["ity"]) for d in metadata_dicts)
    return link_type_records

def extract_images(query, num_images):
    url = get_query_url(query)
    logger.info("Souping")
    soup = get_soup(url, REQUEST_HEADER)
    logger.info("Extracting image urls")
    link_type_records = extract_images_from_soup(soup)
    return itertools.islice(link_type_records, num_images)

def get_raw_image(url):
    req = Request(url, headers=REQUEST_HEADER)
    resp = urlopen(req)
    return resp.read()

def save_image(raw_image, image_type, save_directory):
    extension = image_type if image_type else 'jpg'
    file_name = uuid.uuid4().hex
    save_path = os.path.join(save_directory, file_name)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as image_file:
        image_file.write(raw_image)

def download_images_to_dir(images, save_directory, num_images):
    for i, (url, image_type) in enumerate(images):
        try:
            logger.info("Making request (%d/%d): %s", i, num_images, url)
            raw_image = get_raw_image(url)
            save_image(raw_image, image_type, save_directory)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)

def run(query, save_directory, num_images=100):
    query = '+'.join(query.split())
    logger.info("Extracting image links")
    images = extract_images(query, num_images)
    logger.info("Downloading images")
    download_images_to_dir(images, save_directory, num_images)
    logger.info("Finished")

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Scrape Google images')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', default='bananas', type=str, help='search term')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--num_images', default=1, type=int, help='num images to save')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', default='/Users/Images/', type=str, help='save directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    run(args.search, args.directory, args.num_images)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As for saving the images as actual jpg or png files, looks like adding this

> " + "." + extension"

The full row now looks like this:

> save_path = os.path.join(save_directory, file_name + "." + extension)

fixed the issue as to saving the image in the actual extension as promised by the script.

**Second Update:**

```
import sys
```

this import was already included in the script I found. I found through this site that I can return

```
sys.argv[2]
```

So according to **sys** which is -The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. I included this to the script to return the uuid alongside the actual search terms like so:

```
file_name = uuid.uuid4().hex + "-" + sys.argv[2]
```

But now, as for running this script through mysql workbench on a table that has a list of queries to parse- I'm not sure how long it will take me to figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated. I would like to run this script on a large list of queries, without getting kicked off the search engine.